# FileNotFoundException with multifile upload in Wicket

Tags: java, ajax, file-upload, wicket

We are using Wicket 6+ and have a strange error on FileUpload.writeTo(file).
It's happening only to certain types of files (docx,xlsx,java) and only in one form. The same exact code works to attach files just fine in other places. Any help? Thank you.

HTML:

```
<div wicket:id="filesInput"/>
```

Java:

```
add(new org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.upload.MultiFileUploadField("filesInput", 
                    new PropertyModel<Collection<FileUpload>>(this, "uploads"), 5));
```

Error thrown on line  fileUpload.writeTo(file); when called from form onSubmit.

```
private void writeToFile(FileUpload fileUpload, Attachment attachment) {
    if (fileUpload == null) {
        return;
    }
    File file = AttachmentUtils.getFile(attachment, jtracHome);
    try {
        fileUpload.writeTo(file);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Error log:

```
2013-05-03 12:57:23,731 [http-bio-8084-exec-9] ERROR [org.apache.wicket.DefaultExceptionMapper] -  Unexpected error occurred
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Method onFormSubmitted of interface org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IFormSubmitListener targeted at [SpaceItemViewForm [Component id = form]] on component [SpaceItemViewForm [Component id = form]] threw an exception
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:268)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:216)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:240)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:226)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:840)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:254)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:211)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:282)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:244)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:188)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\aeb\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2.1\apache-tomcat-7.0.27.0_base\temp\upload_9108b655_6177_4450_8e82_a767f101dd40_1997755963.tmp (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at info.jtrac.JtracImpl.writeToFile(JtracImpl.java:405)
    at info.jtrac.JtracImpl.storeScopeOfWork(JtracImpl.java:2053)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:301)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:198)
    at $Proxy11.storeScopeOfWork(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:301)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy12.storeScopeOfWork(Unknown Source)
    at info.jtrac.wicket.SpaceItemViewFormPanel$SpaceItemViewForm.onSubmit(SpaceItemViewFormPanel.java:433)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form$9.component(Form.java:1246)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form$9.component(Form.java:1240)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:274)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrder(Visits.java:245)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1239)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:921)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:767)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:700)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\aib\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2.1\apache-tomcat-7.0.27.0_base\temp\upload_9108b655_6177_4450_8e82_a767f101dd40_1997755963.tmp (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.upload.DiskFileItem.write(DiskFileItem.java:439)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.upload.FileUpload.writeTo(FileUpload.java:234)
    at info.jtrac.JtracImpl.writeToFile(JtracImpl.java:402)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is the code where the exception is coming from:

```
if (!outputFile.renameTo(file))
        {
            BufferedInputStream in = null;
            BufferedOutputStream out = null;
            try
            {
                in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(outputFile));
                out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                Streams.copy(in, out);
            }
            finally
            {
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
            }
        }
```

javadoc:

> This method is only guaranteed to work *once*, the first time it is invoked for a
>        particular item. This is because, in the event that the method renames a temporary file, that
>         file will no longer be available to copy or rename again at a later time.

The exception is coming from the opening of the "outputFile" File - as if it is no longer there. Is it possible the renameTo succeeded to do something with the file, but the renameTo method still returned with false? Can you set a breakpoint there and see what is happening? Maybe somehow you DO call it twice?

From renameTo's javadoc:

> Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently
>        platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a
>        file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it
>         might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname
>         already exists.  The return value should always be checked to make sure
>        that the rename operation was successful.

Comment: cserepj, thanks a lot! It's solved the problem. I tried to store the same list of files with two different objects.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the [wicket MultiUploadPage example](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/upload/multi?2) and everything is working.
Give us more details about your page structure, what's different about your page?

WicketApplication.java

```
public class WicketApplication extends WebApplication {

    private Folder uploadFolder = null;

    @Override
    public Class<? extends WebPage> getHomePage(){
        return HomePage.class;
    }

    public Folder getUploadFolder(){
        return uploadFolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(){
        super.init();
        getResourceSettings().setThrowExceptionOnMissingResource(false);
        uploadFolder = new Folder(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "wicket-uploads");
        uploadFolder.mkdirs();
        getApplicationSettings().setUploadProgressUpdatesEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

HomePage.java

```
public class HomePage extends WebPage {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private final FileListView fileListView;

public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters){
    Folder uploadFolder = getUploadFolder();

    final FeedbackPanel uploadFeedback = new FeedbackPanel("uploadFeedback");
    add(uploadFeedback);

    final FileUploadForm simpleUploadForm = new FileUploadForm("simpleUpload");
    add(simpleUploadForm);

    add(new Label("dir", uploadFolder.getAbsolutePath()));
    fileListView = new FileListView("fileList", new LoadableDetachableModel<List<File>>(){

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected List<File> load(){
            return Arrays.asList(getUploadFolder().listFiles());
        }
    });
    add(fileListView);
}

private class FileListView extends ListView<File>{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public FileListView(String name, final IModel<List<File>> files){
        super(name, files);
    }

    @Override
    protected void populateItem(ListItem<File> listItem){
        final File file = listItem.getModelObject();
        listItem.add(new Label("file", file.getName()));
        listItem.add(new Link<Void>("delete"){
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void onClick(){
                Files.remove(file);
                info("Deleted " + file);
            }
        });
    }
}

private class FileUploadForm extends Form<Void>{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final Collection<FileUpload> uploads = new ArrayList<FileUpload>();

    public FileUploadForm(String name){
        super(name);
        setMultiPart(true);
        add(new MultiFileUploadField("fileInput", new PropertyModel<Collection<FileUpload>>(this, "uploads"), 5, true));
        setMaxSize(Bytes.kilobytes(100000));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(){
        for (FileUpload upload : uploads){
            File newFile = new File(getUploadFolder(), upload.getClientFileName());
            try{
                newFile.createNewFile();
                upload.writeTo(newFile);
                HomePage.this.info("saved file: " + upload.getClientFileName());
            } catch (Exception e){
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to write file");
            }
        }
    }
}

private Folder getUploadFolder(){
    return ((WicketApplication) Application.get()).getUploadFolder();
}
```

}

HomePage.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Apache Wicket Quickstart</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="Stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        The multi upload field is based on javascript found
        <a target="_blank" href="http://the-stickman.com/web-development/javascript/upload-multiple-files-with-a-single-file-element/">here</a>.
        <br />
        <br /> Wicket can also handle file uploads via AJAX, please see AJAX
        examples section. AJAX Functionality is not included in this example to
        keep things simple.
        <br />
        <br />

        <form wicket:id="simpleUpload">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Upload form</legend>
                <p>
                <div wicket:id="fileInput" class="mfuex" />
                </p>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload!" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>

        <div><span wicket:id="uploadFeedback" /></div>

        <div>
            <h4>Current files in <span wicket:id="dir">(dir)</span>:</h4>
            <table>
                <tr wicket:id="fileList">
                    <td width="200"><span wicket:id="file">(file)</span></td>
                    <td><a href="#" wicket:id="delete"><img src="delete.gif" border="0" /></a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm trying to find what is different in my code. I also find what the same object works fine in another place. I'm possibly just missing something in the line of setting it. I'll post more details as soon as I can.